# On OnBackPressed() close the popup window

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

Hey I am working on `Xamarin Mvvmcross`, and the requirement is when the popup is shown then disable the outside click of popup, and on device back button click popup should close,

I am extending the `MvxFragment`
and on `public override void OnBackPressed()` it gives an error

> No suitable method found to override

so what can I use so that I detect the back press

Comment: You mentioned fragment, so is it a popup window or a dialog?

Comment: PUT A CANCEL BUTTON IN THAT POPUP

Comment: If it is a `DialogFragment` you can call `setCancelable(false)` so it cannot be dismissed by back button and outside touch. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#setCancelable(boolean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to know if you pressed the back button of the device put

```
public void onBackPressed(){
//put something like a Log here
}
```

in your activity.